What does this symbol do? Box with 1
A box with an input and an output, and the number "1" inside it.
There is also boxes with -1 on the diagram, but I am guessing they reverse the polarity of the signal.


Can you you a picture of the symbol you are talking about?

Without seeing it, could be a buffer. It immensely helps to have the actual symbol visible, because styling can convey meaning too. The context can help too, so if possible don't just snip the box, but show more of the actual diagram you found it in.

These are blocks with numbers in. They have no particular meaning in an electrical engineering context.

I’m voting to close this question because it is off-topic.

@lundin its a mix of blocks and electrical components, I have never seen a diagram like this before. Only drew a small part of it here.

Based on the "1+0.3s" in the denominator I would assume this is a block diagram of some kind of dynamical system. All blocks then would represent multiplication by the value inside. It looks like the switch is there to allow switching between metric and imperial units, maybe converting millimeters to hundreth's of an inch.
The "multiply by 1" block is obviously then redundant, but it might better convey "choosing between two scaling factors", rather than "skipping the scaling".
Note: The "1/(1+0.3s)" block is technically also a multiplication, but in the Laplace domain, resulting in a low-pass filter response.

Yes, you might be right, but its not strictly a block diagram, its actually a mix of block and electrical components.
